# SQL query to avoid loop or cursor to fetch record

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as follows

```
Table #1 has column UserId and UserName

Table #2 has column MenuId and MenuName

Table #3 has column MappingId, UserId, MenuId
```

(In Table #3 columns UserId and MenuId has foreign key relationship with Table #1 userId and Table #2 MenuId respectively.)

I want select statement like

```
UserName, MenuName, AllowedDisallowedFlag

Where 

UserName is Names of User From Table #1

MenuName is Names of Menu from Table #2
```

and `AllowedDisallowedFlag` will be true if UserName and MenuName combination exist in Table #3 otherwise it will be false.

Is there any way to achieve this without using Cursors or loops ?

Comment: Yes, the normal SQL way is to use [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) .

Comment: @oded Can u help me with query I mean How to use join to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UserName,
    MenuName,
    CASE WHEN Table3.UserID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Allowed
    FROM Table1
    CROSS JOIN Table2
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.UserID = Table3.userID 
    AND Table3.MenuID = Table2.MenuID
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b715/1)

Comment: +1 although you also haven't taken into account what _combination of user and menu_ actually means.

Comment: yes it works only change is in case statement

SELECT DISTINCT
    UserName,
    MenuName,
    **Allowed=**
    CASE WHEN Table3.UserID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 **end** 
    FROM Table1
    CROSS JOIN Table2
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.UserID = Table3.userID 
    AND Table3.MenuID = Table2.MenuID

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think if there is no record in Table3 like user A + menu B it means that menu B is not allowed to user A, so the flag should be 0. Do you think the OP has an other logic? It seems a simple menurigth storing question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Combination of User and Menu means In Table #3 I am mapping user with menu so all thous menuId which I want to show to particular user are mapped in Table # 3. Hopes It clears your doubt.

Comment: @TimSchmelter may I understand for what you would like to point, but if you try the SQL Fiddle, and adds a user without menuright or a new menu it is also working, because of the CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query (I haven't executed):

```
SELECT
(SELECT UserName FROM Table#1 T1 WHERE T1.UserId=T2.UserID) AS UserName,
(SELECT MenuName FROM Table#2 T3 WHERE T3.MenuId=T2.MenuID) AS MenuName,
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(UserId,'')<>'' AND ISNULL(MenuID,'')<>'' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS AllowedDisallowedFlag FROM Table#3 T2
```

Note: provided UserID and MenuID are unique.

Comment: NO let me put my question like this I want in first column all user name (all that are present in table #1) in second column menu name(all the menu present in table #2 against each user name) and in third column True if user name is mapped to menu id in table # 3 else false

Comment: Please try this: `select t1.UserName,t2.MenuName,
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_3 t3 where t3.UserID=t1.UserID and t3.MenuID=t2.MenuID)>0 then 1 else 0 end) AS AllowedDisallowedFlag 
From Table_1 t1, Table_2 t2`